# C block division c language

Tags: c

I have some problem in understanding the pointer

I have matrix then I divided it to small block by using

```
 tiles_num = n /tile;
// Allocate blocked matrix
Ah = (REAL **) malloc( tiles_num *  tiles_num * sizeof(REAL *));
if (Ah == NULL) {
    printf("ALLOCATION ERROR (Ah)\n");
    exit(-1);
}

for (j = 0; j <  tiles_num *  tiles_num; j++) {
    Ah[j]=(REAL *) malloc(tile * tile * sizeof(REAL));
    if (Ah[ j ] == NULL) {
        printf("ALLOCATION ERROR (Ah[%d] )\n", j);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

where (tiles_num is the number of small block, n is the size one dimension of matrix, tile is size of small block)

After that I want to give a function just a pointer to the starting of superblock then the function will move between the small block
for example if I have N=12 and the superblock=4 and the smallblock=2.
1-so how I can give function point of starting the superblock then move inside by small block?

2-I want to know if A[k] is the same as A+k to refernce ?

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C. Doing this can be dangerous because if you forget to include the header for `malloc`, the compiler will assume that `malloc` returns `int`. With the cast, you are forcing the compiler to interpret the result of `malloc` as an `int` converted to a `REAL *` or `REAL **`, which will cause big problems if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(REAL *)`. Without the cast, the compiler must emit a diagnostic message (typically a warning) and it will be clear that you've forgotten to include `<stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can just pass Ah to your function, since Ah is a pointer to the list of small blocks.  Does that answer your question?

Regarding your second question, A[k] is the value at address A+k.  So A[k] is actually equivalent to *(A+k), or conversely, &(A[k]) is equivalent to A+k.